# Why are my MySQL joins slow?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have a single query that joins tables. This is the select statement:

```
SELECT *, A.id AS id, 
       A.username AS username, 
       G.desc AS customer_desc, 
       H.id AS counter, 
       SUM( F.amount_paid ) 
FROM tblcheckin AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblrate AS B ON B.id = A.rate_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblrefaccom_type AS C ON C.id = A.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblcust_bill AS D ON D.check_in_id = A.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblroom AS E ON E.room_no = A.room_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblpayment AS F ON F.check_in_id = A.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblrefcust_type AS G ON G.id = A.customer_desc
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblindex AS H ON A.id = H.check_in_id
WHERE A.check_out =  "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
GROUP BY F.check_in_id
ORDER BY check_out, check_in
```

Result: `Showing rows 0 - 11 ( 12 total, Query took 7.4061 sec)`

And this is the `Explain SQL`

[image]

This is my what I did so far:
I set `optimizer_search_depth = 0` since I thought it would work as mentioned here [Joining many tables in mySQL](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/04/20/joining-many-tables-in-mysql-optimizer_search_depth/).

What am I doing wrong here? I appreciate each and every feedback. Thank you.

UPDATE. Problem solved. I added index to the check_in_id column from tblpayment, tblcust_bill, and tblindex. Here's the new `Explain SQL`:

[image]

Comment: You're using the pernicious MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. Read this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-extensions.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've read the article and added F.check_in_id to the select list. However, it's still pretty slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your Explain, I can see several of the joins require full table scans.  You probably don't have an index on `A.check_out`, `D.check_in_id`, `F.check_in_id` ( and that's a killer based on the relative number of rows), and `H.check_in_id`.  Which means it's got to scan the whole darn tables A, D, F, and H to find the relevant rows.

Index those 4 rows, and query times should skyrocket.

That having been said, I'm surprised this isn't blazing fast already, even not optimized.  I'm seeing a few tens of thousands of rows in each table - unless those rows are really huge ( bad practice by the way - break text/blob and big columns off into separate tables ), you should be able to get these results in less than 7 seconds.  More like 70 milliseconds I'd expect.  I suspect you have to tweak your mysql server settings - use more ram, increase the buffer sizes, etc.  But those indexes should help a lot.

Comment: I think this is a grand idea, but @OllieJones makes a great point about joining tables you're not even using below.  Take a look at that answer too!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Will certainly try to fix the indices. I'll post an update afterwards.

Comment: let us know if you don't know how to add indexes, I'm sure we can help you.  Basically ALTER TABLE table ADD KEY( column ) is what you want to do.

Comment: Hi. Table F (tblpayment) has 23k rows. It has many-to-1 relationship with tblcheckin. It has a primary key named id. However, in my join statement, I used `tblpayment AS F ON F.check_in_id = A.id`. Any other way to do it? The time consumed for the query has been decreased to 2 seconds by adding indices to tblpayment, tblcust_bill and tblindex. however, the rows being searched are the same. am I doing it right?

Comment: Even if `tblpayment` has many of the same value in the `check_in_id` column, you'll still see a significant increase in speed by indexing it.  You can have multiple indices on a table, and they don't have to be unique.  To answer the question about whether you're doing it right, we'd need to see the updated explain.

Comment: It's solved! 
My mistake was I wasn't adding index to the foreign key, that is check_in_id from tblpayment, tblcust_bill, and tblindex. It's all blazing fast now.
`Showing rows 0 - 11 ( 12 total, Query took 0.0273 sec)` Again thanks! This calls for a celebration LOL.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be left-joining lots of tables that aren't needed to satisfy your query. Will this work, leaving out the extra tables?

```
SELECT A.id AS id, 
       A.username AS username, 
       G.desc AS customer_desc, 
       H.id AS counter, 
       SUM( F.amount_paid ) 
FROM tblcheckin AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblpayment AS F ON F.check_in_id = A.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblrefcust_type AS G ON G.id = A.customer_desc
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblindex AS H ON A.id = H.check_in_id
WHERE A.check_out =  "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
GROUP BY F.check_in_id
ORDER BY check_out, check_in
```

You are using a nasty MySQL hackstension to GROUP BY. Do this instead.

```
GROUP BY A.id, A.username, G.desc, H.id
```

Is `tblcheckin` a table with many rows? If so make sure there's an index on `check_out` and it's declared `NOT NULL`.

Make sure you have indexes on the columns mentioned in the `ON` clauses in your `JOIN` directives, namely:

```
   tblpayment.check_in_id
   tblrefcust_type.id   (maybe already a primary key)
   tblindex.check_in_id
```

Consider putting covering indexes (multicolumn indexes) in your tables. That way the data your query needs from that particular query can be satisfied completely from the index, which will save query lookup disk drive time. Lots of indexes can slow inserts and updates, though.

```
   tblcheckin (cneck_out, id, customer_desc, username)
   tblpayment  (check_in_id, amount_paid)
   tblrefcust_type  (id, desc)
   tblindex        (check_in_id, id)
```

Comment: You know that's a darn good point, B,C,D,E tables dont' seem to matter at all!

Comment: sorry about the question. I forgot to include the "*" in the select. I copied the query that i've been testing this morning. I will edit the question. Again, I apologize.